# Lazy loading implementation

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement lazy loading in angular 5.

app.module.ts

```
  import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
  import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
  import {RouterModule , Routes} from '@angular/router';
  import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
  import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
  import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
  import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 
  '@angular/common';
  import { DataService } from './data.service';
  import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
  import { ContactComponent } from "./contact/contact.component";
  import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
  @NgModule({
     declarations: [
     AppComponent,
     HomeComponent,
     AboutComponent,
     ContactComponent,
     NavComponent
  ],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  FormsModule,
  RouterModule.forRoot([
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
    {path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent},
  ])
],
providers: [DataService,{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: 
HashLocationStrategy}],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })

export class AppModule { }
```

I want contact and about component to get lazy loaded. How to do that?? Does i need to create some new modules and components for that ??

Comment: I think you need to read this first: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules. Here you have nice working demo: https://github.com/UltimateAngular/angular-lazy-load-demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 2 new modules:

```
ng generate module about --roputing
ng generate module contact --routing
```

Create components for each of these modules:

```
ng generate component about/components/about
ng generate component contact/components/contact
```

Because we used the **--routing** options each of these modules will have an **about-routing.module.ts** and **contact-routing.module.ts** created. Here you need to specify the routes for the modules. Add this to the **about** module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AboutComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

And for the **contact** module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ContactComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Change the **app.module.ts** to:

```
 RouterModule.forRoot([
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
     path: 'about', loadChildren: './about/about.module#AboutModule' },
     path: 'contact', loadChildren: './contact/contact.module#ContactModule' },
  ])
```

Comment: ng generate module about --routing. Its showing
error! src/app/about/about.module.ts already exists.

Comment: @Ronit, you created alreadhy the about module? After the question was posted?

Comment: NO. i have two componenets named about and contacts. I have no module named about

Comment: I got it. already one module was there named as about. Thanks bro

Comment: But i am unable to see the content of about and contact page when i run my app

Answer (score 1):

To achieve lazy loading, you use child routes which refer to the lazy loaded Modules RoutingModule where the child Routes will be resolved further:
**loadChildren: './pages/myPath/myPath.module#MyPathModule'**

MaiModule->MainRoutingModule -> **childRoute=LazyLoadModule** -> LazyLoadRoutingModule

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
 {
   path: 'myPath',
   loadChildren: './pages/myPath/myPath.module#LazyLoadedModule'
 },
]
```

Comment: Bro i am not getting. Can you explain me how to code it

Comment: Your Lazy Loaded Module is a Module that has its own Routing Module. Just like the top level AppModule has its AppRoutingModule. You then just refer in the AppRoutingModule to a childroute that points to the LazyLoadedModule.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your AboutComponent and ContactComponent into separate module which is named as 'LandingModule'. Then you can create a separate routing page for your landing module.

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
 {path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
];
```

After that you need to go to create AppRoutingModule which include app level routing for create lazy loading routes.

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: 'customers',
  loadChildren: './landing/landing.module#LandingModule'
},
{
  path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'
}
];
```

If you want to read more you can visit given links.

- https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules
- https://blog.khophi.co/angular-module-lazy-loading-like-pro/

Adding separate file for routing is a good practice other than keeping all your routes inside your appModule.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create new Module that will your about and related component loading using the child concept link to main app-routing file.

Comment: Please provide better explanations and code samples.